# sudo gem install rmagick fails - mac sierra high - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, rmagick

I cant seem to run

```
sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4'
```

the following errors appears.

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/ext/RMagick
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180118-8026-9kus0w.rb extconf.rb
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 41: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 47: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 50: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config: No such file or directory
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config: No such file or directory
Can't install RMagick 2.15.4. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.
```

the following is the full execution and errors
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c0369567397c376233a7b4419d48fc2d

I think this may be the cause of it from mkmf.log

```
configure_compile_options: checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... -------------------- no

Detected ImageMagick version: 6.9.9
```

I'ved already run this:

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link --force imagemagick@6
```

Im using

```
MacOS Sierra High 

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
```

Comment: try looking into the `mkfm.log` file, it might have some info on which dev files you are missing

Comment: mkfm.log output is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e795529c15d952880b22a6ea68ed5435

Comment: Other installers have been having trouble with High Sierra. I have read about lots of problems using MacPorts. The maintainers have spent a great deal of time dealing with changes from Sierra to High Sierra. So perhaps you are having similar issues. Sorry I know little about Ruby and RMagick. Perhaps they have RMagick fixed. So you could try installing from MacPorts.

Comment: I have the same OS X version, and the same ImageMagic (6.9.9) installed. I believe the thing is you're trying to install the gem from `sude` - why do you need it at all??

Comment: u mean sudo ? otherwise it doesnt have enough rights

Comment: did you ever solve this?